# How to get NOAA web token for data access?

Tags: query

I've been searching the NCDC/NCEI data access site for how to get this mythical 'token' we are supposed to request to access data.  This page says nothing about it: https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/support/access-data-service-api-user-documentation

It gives examples of how to display a web page of data (no token required) but when I try to use curl I'm told half the request is missing (it's not).  I'm wondering if using a token might fix this problem, and if so, how do I get the thing?

My request and error messages are as follows:

> ```
> curl https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/access-data-service/api/v1/data?dataset=global-marine&dataTypes=WIND_DIR,WIND_SPEED&stations=AUCE&startDate=2016-01-01&endDate=2016-01-02
> ```
>
> > > testdat.txt
>
> ```
> [1] 5991
>
> [2] 5992
>
> [3] 5993
>
> [4] 5994
>
> [2]   Done                    dataTypes=WIND_DIR,WIND_SPEED
>
> [3]-  Done                    stations=AUCE
>
> [4]+  Done                    startDate=2016-01-01
>
> bvh-2:~ brianvanthull2$ {"errorMessage":"Bad Request","errorCode":400,"errors": [{"field":"startDate","message":"A
> ```
>
> start date is required.","value":null},
>   {"field":"endDate","message":"An end date is
>   required.","value":null}]}

Comment: v2 uses the token request from here https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/token

Comment: Put complex URLs with "&" and so on inside single quote marks, or your shell will split it into multiple commands which is why you get those `[2] 5992` outputs - that's the shell starting jobs...

Comment: Works fine with double quotes on Windows `curl -o test "https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/access-data-service/api/v1/data?dataset=global-marine&dataTypes=WIND_DIR,WIND_SPEED&stations=AUCE&startDate=2016-01-01&endDate=2016-01-02"`

Comment: Ah, the quotes!  Thank you, that seems to have solved it.

Comment: actually it was the quotes combined with the -o redirect instead of the > redirect.